# Python gives me the error sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

cursor = con.cursor()
def tablo_olustur():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE veritabani(İsim TEXT, Yazar TEXT, Yayınevi TEXT, Sayfa INTEGER")
    con.commit()
def veri_ekle():
    cursor.execute("insert into veritabani Values('İstanbul Hatırası', 'Ahmet Ümit', 'Everest', 561)")
    con.commit()

tablo_olustur()
veri_ekle()

con.close()
```

It gives me the sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input error in the line 7. How do I solve this?

Comment: You are missing `)` after `Sayfa INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the error :

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE veritabani(İsim TEXT, Yazar TEXT, Yayınevi TEXT, Sayfa INTEGER")
```

it should be like

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE veritabani(İsim TEXT, Yazar TEXT, Yayınevi TEXT, Sayfa INTEGER)")
```

and now might work just balancing you parenthesis